# Formly - How can I link the field to the model of a custom template

Tags: angular8, angular-formly, angular-ngselect

I am using Angular 8 with Formly for creating a select input type with search. As a solution, I found that `ng-select` will suit me well.

**The question is how can I link the `[model]` directive to the Formly field which uses my custom template ?**

Note: I do not want to use a plain text, like `model.my.special.key` - I need to give it something general. This way I can use it with other fields that I want to make use of this selector with search.

In more details what I did so far:

1. I have created a new `@Component` that extends `FieldType` and has a template that uses the  selector for displaying the options it receives as input

```js
@Component({
  selector: "SelectorWithSearchModule",
  template: `
    <ng-select
      [items]="to.options"
      bindLabel="label"
      bindValue="code"
      labelForId="code"
      placeholder="{{ to.label }}"
      [multiple]="to.multiple"
      clearAllText="Clear"
      (change)="onChange($event)"
      [(ngModel)]="what-to-put-in-here?"
    >
    </ng-select>
  `
})
export class SirutaModule extends FieldType implements OnInit {}
```

2. I have declared this new Component in `app.module.ts` and extented the Formly types with it:
   eg:

```js
import { SelectorWithSearchModule } from "./types/selector/special-selector.component"; // declaration
...
FormlyModule.forRoot({ // from here begins the Formly definition
types: [
{
  name: "special-selector",
  component: SelectorWithSearchModule 
}
]
```

3. I am using the `special-selector` name when defining new Formly fields

```js
{
  className: "col-8",
  type: "special-selector",
  key: "my.hierarchy.key",
  templateOptions: {
    label: "some label here",
    options: ["option_one", "option_two"]
  }
}
```

**I want that in the end, the key `my.hierarchy.key` to contain the value user selected in my custom template, but it is not very clear how.**